# How to extract images from pdf and save each as a jpeg with C# & itext7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, itext7

this is a C# winforms project

Given a file folder, need to open any pdf file and for each file,
evaluate every object.  If the object is an image, extract it, convert it and save it
as a Jpeg file in that same folder.

```
    private void btnExtractImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtSourcePdf.Text);
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fi.FullName));
                string fNm = fi.Name.Replace(".pdf", ""); //Filename without the extension
                int pgs = doc.GetNumberOfPages();
                for (int pg = 1; pg <= pgs; pg++)
                {
                    PdfPage pdfPage = doc.GetPage(pg);
                    PdfFormXObject xObj = pdfPage.CopyAsFormXObject(doc);
                    iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(xObj);
                    //good so far.
                    //need to turn this xObj or img into a jpg and save to disk
                    ...

                }
                // This works, however it creates a .dat file, not a .jpg file
                // int objs = doc.GetNumberOfPdfObjects();
                // for (int o = 1; o <= objs; o++)
                // {
                //    PdfObject obj = doc.GetPdfObject(o);
                //    if (obj != null && obj.IsStream())
                //    {
                //         byte[] b;
                //         try
                //         {
                //          // Get decoded stream bytes.
                //              b = ((PdfStream)obj).GetBytes();
                //         }
                //         catch (Exception)
                //         {
                //            //Get originally encoded stream bytes
                //              b = ((PdfStream)obj).GetBytes(false);
                //         }


                //         using (FileStream fos = new FileStream(String.Format(txtSourcePdf.Text + "/" + fNm + "{0}.jpg", o), FileMode.Create))
                //         {
                //             fos.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                //         }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: By "image" you mean bitmap images? `iText.Layout.Element.Image` is not about bitmap images...

Comment: Yes.  I need to extract and save an image file, like .jpg, .gif, .bmp -I'd like a jpg but it doesn't matter.